# Performance with Manually Scaled Bitmaps across multiple devices

Tags: java, android, bitmap, scaling

I am working on an Android game that is pretty heavy in terms of image resources.  One of the challenges that I am facing is that I need to manually scale the graphics to match the different screen sizes.  The reason for not allowing Android to auto-scale is that the game is dependent upon the graphics not getting stretched or skewed.  I will be potentially switching in 3-4 bitmaps per screen press, so performance is key (I already have a caching operation set up to help w/ this).

After considering the problem and the diversity of Android devices out there, I decided on the following approach to target as many devices as possible:

1. Make density-specific graphics (via http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html and the other suggestions listed in dev.android.com  )
2. Rather than making many versions of an image for the different screen sizes, create one very large image that covers all target screens and use manual scaling to reduce its size to match the device.

So far, this approach is going well, but I need to squeeze more performance out of my custom BitmapScaler class.  I have leveraged the code base found here to suit my own needs:  http://zerocredibility.wordpress.com/2011/01/27/android-bitmap-scaling/ .

With that being said, here are my questions:  Does anyone have any comments on the viability of my approach for solving the screen destiny / screen size problem?  I am aware that I am trading performance for convenience here.  Can anyone suggest a way to squeeze out better performance in my bitmap scaling operation (Below)?

```
    public class BitmapScaler {

private Bitmap scaledBitmap;

public Bitmap getScaledBitmap()
{
return scaledBitmap;
}

/* IMPORANT NOTES:
* The process of scaling bitmaps for Android is not a straightforward process. In order to
* help preserve memory on the phone, you need to go through several steps:
*
* 1. Decode the target resource, but use the inJustDecodeBounds option. This allows you to "sample"
* the resource without actually incurring the hit of loading the entire resource. If set to true, the decoder will return null
* (no bitmap), but the out... fields will still be set, allowing the caller to query the bitmap without having to allocate
* the memory for its pixels.
* 2. Determine the new aspects of your bitmap, particularly the scale and sample. If the sample size is set to a value > 1,
* requests the decoder to subsample the original image, returning a smaller image to save memory. The sample size is the number
* of pixels in either dimension that correspond to a single pixel in the decoded bitmap. For example, inSampleSize == 4 returns
* an image that is 1/4 the width/height of the original, and 1/16 the number of pixels. Any value <= 1 is treated the same as 1.
* Note: the decoder will try to fulfill this request, but the resulting bitmap may have different dimensions that precisely what
* has been requested. Also, powers of 2 are often faster/easier for the decoder to honor.
* 3. Prescale the bitmap as much as possible, rather than trying to fully decode it in memory. This is a less
* expensive operation and allows you to "right size" your image.
* 4. Create your new bitmap, applying a matrix to "fine tune" the final resize.
*
* Partial Ref: http://zerocredibility.wordpress.com/2011/01/27/android-bitmap-scaling/
*/

public BitmapScaler(Resources resources, int targetResourceID, int targetWidth, int targetHeight)
{
BitmapInfo originalInfo = getOriginalBitmapInfo(resources, targetResourceID);
BitmapInfo newInfo = getScaledBitmapInfo(targetHeight, targetWidth, originalInfo);
prescaleScaledBitmap(resources, targetResourceID, newInfo);
scaleScaledBitmap(newInfo);
}

private void scaleScaledBitmap(BitmapInfo newInfo)
{

int ScaledHeight = scaledBitmap.getHeight();
int ScaledWidth = scaledBitmap.getWidth();

float MatrixWidth = ((float)newInfo.width) / ScaledWidth;
float MatrixHeight = ((float)newInfo.height) / ScaledHeight;

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postScale(MatrixWidth, MatrixHeight);

scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0, ScaledWidth, ScaledHeight, matrix, true);
}

private void prescaleScaledBitmap(Resources resources, int targetResourceID, BitmapInfo newInfo)
{
BitmapFactory.Options scaledOpts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
scaledOpts.inSampleSize = newInfo.sample;
scaledBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, targetResourceID, scaledOpts);
}

private BitmapInfo getOriginalBitmapInfo(Resources resources, int targetResourceID)
{
BitmapFactory.Options bitOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bitOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, targetResourceID, bitOptions);

return new BitmapInfo(bitOptions.outHeight,bitOptions.outWidth);
}

private BitmapInfo getScaledBitmapInfo(int targetHeight, int targetWidth, BitmapInfo originalBitmapInfo)
{
float HeightRatio = targetHeight / (float)originalBitmapInfo.height;
float WidthRatio = targetWidth / (float)originalBitmapInfo.width;

BitmapInfo newInfo = new BitmapInfo(0,0);

if (HeightRatio > WidthRatio)
{
newInfo.scale = WidthRatio;
newInfo.width = targetWidth;
newInfo.height = (int)(newInfo.scale * originalBitmapInfo.height);
} else {
newInfo.scale = HeightRatio;
newInfo.height = targetHeight;
newInfo.width = (int)(newInfo.scale * originalBitmapInfo.width);
}

newInfo.sample = 1;

int SampleHeight = originalBitmapInfo.height;
int SampleWidth = originalBitmapInfo.width;

while (true) {
if (SampleWidth / 2 < newInfo.width || SampleHeight / 2 < newInfo.height) {
break;
}
SampleWidth /= 2;
SampleHeight /= 2;
newInfo.sample *= 2;
}

return newInfo;
    }

}
```

Thanks!